# Terraform "file name too long" when executing with "null_resource" "apply"

Tags: terraform, jq, kubectl

I'm trying to execute the following command:
`` kubectl get cm aws-auth -n kube-system -o json | jq --arg add "`cat additional_roles_aws_auth.yaml`" '.data.mapRoles += $add' | kubectl apply -f - ``
as part of a local Terraform exeuction as follows:

```
locals {
  kubeconfig = yamlencode({
    apiVersion      = "v1"
    kind            = "Config"
    current-context = "terraform"
    clusters = [{
      name = module.eks.cluster_id
      cluster = {
        certificate-authority-data = module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data
        server                     = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
      }
    }]
    contexts = [{
      name = "terraform"
      context = {
        cluster = module.eks.cluster_id
        user    = "terraform"
      }
    }]
    users = [{
      name = "terraform"
      user = {
        token = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.this.token
      }
    }]
  })
}
resource "null_resource" "apply" {
  triggers = {
    kubeconfig = base64encode(local.kubeconfig)
    cmd_patch  = <<-EOT
      kubectl get cm aws-auth -n kube-system -o json | jq --arg add "`cat additional_roles_aws_auth.yaml`" '.data.mapRoles += $add' | kubectl apply -f -
    EOT
  }
    provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    environment = {
      KUBECONFIG = self.triggers.kubeconfig
    }
    command = self.triggers.cmd_patch
  }
}
```

Executing the same command outside of Terraform, plainly on the command line works fine.
However, I always get the following error when executing as part of the Terraform script:

```
│ ': exit status 1. Output:
│ iAic2FtcGxlLWNsdXN0ZXI...WaU5ERXdNekEiCg==":
│ open
│ ImFwaVZlcnNpb24iOiAidjEiy...RXdNekEiCg==:
│ file name too long
```

Anybody any ideas what the issues could be ?

Comment: What is in the `local.kubeconfig`?

Comment: `KUBECONFIG` environment variable is a list of paths to the config file, not the config file itself: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#:~:text=The%20KUBECONFIG%20environment%20variable%20is%20a%20list%20of%20paths%20to%20configuration%20files.. Judging from the code output, you either did a `base64encode` on the file path or the file itself. If used on the file path, you can do a `base64decode(self.triggers.kubeconfig)`. Otherwise, you need to provide the path.

Comment: I added the local.kubeconfig Code. Sorry that I missed that.

Comment: @MarkoE Thanks a lot. That hint helped me already a lot. I don't get the error message anymore. I'm added the following to the kubectl statements:
--kubeconfig <(echo $KUBECONFIG | base64 --decode)
And I don't get the error anymore. Even though I don't get an error message, the changes are not applied successfully, so something is still off.

Comment: Fixed the other issue. The file that I use to inject additional content needs to be located at the root of the root module that I use. 
@MarkoE Works now, thanks a lot! Please submit an answer that I can mark as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment: the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable needs to be a list of configuration files and not the content of the file itself [1]:

> The KUBECONFIG environment variable is a list of paths to configuration files.

The original problem was that the content of the file was encoded in `base64` format [2] and used in that format without decoding it before. Thankfully, Terraform has both functions built-in, so using `base64decode` [3] would return the "normal" file content. Still, it would be the **file content** and not **path to the config file**. Based on the other comments, I guess the important thing to note is the `additional_roles_aws_auth.yaml` file has to be in the same directory as the root module. As the command is a bit more complicated, I am not sure if you could use Terraform built-in `path` object [4] to make sure the file is searched for in the root of the module:

```
kubectl get cm aws-auth -n kube-system -o json | jq --arg add "`cat ${path.root}/additional_roles_aws_auth.yaml`" '.data.mapRoles += $add' | kubectl apply -f -
```

---

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#set-the-kubeconfig-environment-variable

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/base64encode

[3] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/base64decode

[4] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/references#filesystem-and-workspace-info

Answer (score 0):

The base64 encoded kubeconfig is called in your command so you must decode it:

```
kubectl <YOUR_COMMAND> --kubeconfig <(echo $KUBECONFIG | base64 --decode)
```